# Storing mesh data values

Tags: unity-game-engine, data-structures, shader, mesh

I am creating meshes based off of a CSV files in the format "x,y,z,dataValue". Based on the data value, I am coloring the vertex. For example, for data value 10-20, it will be a dark green, and for 20-30 a lighter green, etc... I have this working, but I would like to be able to create an analysis tool for the mesh. Basically I want to show the data value of the point being hovered over by the mouse. So, if they are hovering over a vertex, it shows "data value = x". However, once the mesh is created I can only access the color, that data value is basically transformed into a material. I need a way to store the data value relative to each vertex.

I have about 450,000 lines of data, so I need an efficient way to find the data value. I have thought of two options: store the vertices mapped to a data value, and search through the map to find the right data value (I think this might me too slow).. OR store the data value in the shader for each vertex and then when hovering over the vertex, access the shader to grab the data value. I'm not sure how to do the second approach, or if it is the better way to go about it. I'm just looking for an efficient way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to organize your vertex data in an [Octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

First get the hit point by the mouse ray and the `MeshCollider` via [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), and 
then search for the vertex near the hit point in the octree.